# Getting Out of memory errors when running query with high limit but with little amount of objects in Neo4j 2.1 and Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am running basically `MATCH (n:Node) return n LIMIT 2147483644` and it works, however if I do `MATCH (n:Node) return n LIMIT 2147483645` (just one more) it crashes with the following (in the JVM):

`[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
Neo4jClient.NeoException: OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit`

However the amount of nodes of type n is not even a 100. Please note that the limit works for int32.MaxValue - 3 but it doesn't work for int32.MaxValue - 2.

If I do this directly into the web browser shell, or the console it works.

Has anyone experienced this behavior?

Comment: I'm curious what's your use case is for using a limit of 2g?

Comment: We have a generic interface to retrieve up to a limit of items (pagination). For unit testing, sometimes we want to retrieve all the items to check that we have the exact number of items that we want, and we do this by retrieving the maximum amount of items we want. It is a way to compromise between testing and not changing/adding new methods.

Comment: to get all items omit the `LIMIT` statement completely. Looks like internally usage of `LIMIT` spawns an array of the requested size.

Comment: Yes, I know that that brings everything, but in 2.0.x I could use LIMIT int32.MaxValue without a problem.

Comment: if it's a regression, file a ticket at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues

Comment: What does your .NET code look like? I can run: `var cypher = client.Cypher.Match("n").Return(n => n.As<Node<string>>()).Limit(int.MaxValue); var res = cypher.Results.ToList();` against a 2.1.1 server using N4J 1.0.0.656 and this works fine, node wise this is against a DB with ~600 nodes, so tiny really.